# Removing elements meeting criteria in both arrays MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have two arrays of unequal length. Say A of a longer length and B of a shorter length. I wish to remove all elements from both A and B which meet a criteria - if there is a value in A which is between +/- 0.1 of a value in B then remove this element from both A and B. Remove only as many values from A as from B - ie., there can be non unique elements. If there are multiple elements that can be equivalently removed from A & B, remove the smaller element of B first and the larger element of A first.

Example:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 3 4 ]
B = [ 3.1, 2.9, 5]
```

Then 3  and 3 is removed from A and 3.1 and 2.9 is removed from B.

How do I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: An issue with this is that the solution is not unique. Consider `A=[1 2 3 3 4], B=[3.1, 3.05, 2.9]`: you could remove _any two_ elements from `B`. Or, for a more complicated example, `A=[1 2 3 3.1 4], B=[3.1, 2.9, 5]`: you can remove `3.1` from `B` paired with `3` from `A`, and you are stuck. But if instead you remove `2.9` from `B` paired with `3` from `A`, you can go on and remove the other pair (`3.1` from `A`, `3.1` from `B`). So I'd say the problem is not well defined. You need to specify which of the solutions / procedures you use

Comment: @LuisMendo good point. we always remove the lower of the B first. So 2.9 removed with 3, then 3.1 removed with 3.1

Comment: And does the lower of the `B` get removed with the lower of the `A`? That is, sort both arrays and proceed left to right on each array?

Comment: @LuisMendo lower of B with larger of A .

Comment: You probably need to apply a loop on the sorted arrays, removing one element from each array in each iteration, and proceeding with the reduced arrays for the next iteration

Comment: okay thats not hard

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ismembertol`:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 3 4 ];
B = [ 3.1, 2.9, 5];

Aind = ismembertol(A,B,0.1);
Bind = ismembertol(B,A,0.1);

A(Aind) = [];
B(Bind) = [];
```

`ismembertol` perform a comparison using a tolerance (0.1 in this case)

A similar result can also be achieve with:

```
lim = 0.1+10^-10 % +10^-10 so we avoid the floating point precision error.

Aind = any(abs(A-B.')<=lim,1)
Bind = any(abs(A-B.')<=lim,2)

A(Aind) = []
B(Bind) = []
```

Noticed that this second solution is not memory efficient. It is only suited for small array since it create a `length(A)*length(B)` matrice.